# Multiobject Comparable/Comparator interface

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, comparator

Is there any standard interface or approach usable in collections/streams (max, sort) for the situation where one might need to compare on multiple sides/objects at once?

The signature could be something like

```
  compare(T... toCompare)
```

instead of

```
  compare(T object1, T object2)
```

what I would like is do an implementation that works for comparing operations in Java APIs. But from what I saw, I think I have to adhere mandatory to unitary comparations.

UPDATE: Practical example: I'd like to have a Comparator implementation interpreted by Collections/Stream.max() that allowed me to make multiside comparisons not unitary comparisons (i.e, that accepts multiple T in the compare method). The max function returns the element so that element is the winner of a comparison mechanism, custom implemented, of it against ALL the others, not the winner of n battles 1 vs 1.

UPDATE2: More specific example:
I have (Pineapple,Pizza,Yogurt), and max returns the item such that my custom 1 -> n comparison returns biggest quotient. This quotient could be something like degreeOfYumie. So Pineapple is more yummie than Pizza+Yogurt, Pizza is equally yummie than Pineapple+yogurt, and Yogurt is equally yummie than Pizza+Pineapple. So the winner is Pineaple. If I did that unitary, all the ingredients would be equally yummie. Is there any mechanism for implementing a comparator/comparable as that? Perhaps a "sortable" interface that works on collections, streams and queues?

Comment: And what would it return?

Comment: An integer (if it's bigger than any, euqals or little than any) or the object T winner, but it must accept multiple objects for the comparison, like a multiside comparison

Comment: Uh, sorry but you don't really make sense; maybe you are looking for something like Guava's [`Ordering#max()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#max(E,%20E,%20E,%20E...))?

Comment: I don't make sense because I'm talking in abstract. I don'0t mind if it is some kin d of comparator and accepts all the elements for the comparison and returns the winner, or somethign like a comparable, or returning and index, but I need a multisde comparison, not one by one. The arbitrary way of interpreting the integer returned value I don't mind as long as it allows comparing multiple objects at once.

Comment: Yes, similar to that Guava thing, but intepreted in collections.sort() and the like

Comment: While this question seems very interesting, I can't help feeling that it would be much better if we knew what the actual problem is, so that we can help in a more realistic manner. Smells like [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, sorry.

Comment: "I don't make sense because I'm talking in abstract.", I think you're trying to ask "How to define the compare(...) method's return value?", which is obviously not enough given we don't know what you want to achieve. Try to make multiple example inputs and outputs, that would help everyone (simple numbers are sufficient, because it's easy to extrapolate to objects), heck, you may even solve it yourself by defining what you want :) I've been there...

Comment: There's `Collections.max(collection, comparator)` which takes an arbitrary number of objects and finds the "maximum" one, as determined by the comparator. There's also `Collections.min`. If the objects have a natural order (i.e. they are Comparable) then you don't need to provide a Comparator.

Comment: That's the perfect case. I'd like to have a Comparator implementation used by Collections.max that allow me to make multiside comparisons not unitary comparisons (i.e, that accepts multiple T in the compare method)

Comment: What should be the result if the object is neither greater than all, nor less than all, nor equal to all?

Comment: Your “practical example” just repeats your question with other words. There’s nothing *practical* in it.

Comment: @zeroflag. I wouldn't mind the result, just that the interface allow implementing a multiside comparison. I would adapt to any logic if so (integer, T, or boolean, whatever)

Comment: How can pineapple be more yummie than and as yummie as pizza at the same time?

Comment: Pineapple is as yummie as pizza, but pinneaple is more yummie than the combination of the rest of elements (yougurt,pizza) that is the logic of my comparator. My comparator looks the element which is to a most extend yummier than the combination of the rest (average of yummie or whatever). But the thing is you need all other elements for obtaining the comparing quotient index

Comment: You never mentioned _combination_ , but that's the key point. What you really seem to need is not a special comparator but a combination type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a specialized `interface`. If you have a `Comparator` that conforms to the specification, it will be transitive and allow comparing multiple objects. To get the maximum out of three or more elements, simply use, e.g.

```
Stream.of(42, 8, 17).max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
// or
Stream.of("foo", "BAR", "Baz").max(String::compareToIgnoreCase)
      .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

If you are interested in the index of the max element, you can do it like this:

```
List<String> list=Arrays.asList("foo", "BAR", "z", "Baz");
int index=IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed()
  .max(Comparator.comparing(list::get, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
  .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalStateException("empty list"));
```

---

Regarding your updated question…
You said you want to establish an ordering based on the quotient of an element’s property and the remaining elements. Let’s think this through

Suppose we have the positive numerical values `a`, `b` and `c` and want to establish an ordering based on `a/(b+c)`, `b/(a+c)` and `c/(a+b)`.

Then we can transform the term by extending the quotients to have a common denominator:

```
  a(a+c)(a+b)      b(b+c)(b+a)      c(c+b)(c+a)
---------------  ---------------  ---------------
(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)  (a+b)(b+c)(a+c)  (a+b)(b+c)(a+c)
```

Since common denominators have no effect on the ordering we can elide them and after expanding the products we get the terms:

```
a³+a²b+a²c+abc   b³+b²a+b²c+abc   c³+c²a+c²b+abc
```

Here we can elide the common summand `abc` as it has no effect on the ordering.

```
a³+a²b+a²c       b³+b²a+b²c       c³+c²a+c²b
```

then factor out again

```
a²(a+b+c)        b²(a+b+c)        c²(a+b+c)
```

to see that we have a common factor which we can elide as it doesn’t affect the ordering so we finally get

```
a²               b²               c²
```

what does this result tell us? Simply that the quotients are proportional to the values `a`, `b` and `c`, thus have *the same ordering*. So there is no need to implement a quotient based comparator when we can prove it to have the same outcome as a simple comparator based on the original values `a`, `b` and `c`.

(The picture would be different if negative values were allowed, but since allowing negative values would create the possibility of getting zero as denominator, they are off this use case anyway)

---

It should be emphasized that any other result for a particular comparator would prove that that comparator is unusable for standard `Comparator` use cases. If the combined values of all other elements had an effect on the resulting order, in other words, adding another element to the relation would change the ordering, how should an operation like adding an element to a `TreeSet` or inserting it at the right position of a sorted list work?

Comment: I want to conform to comparator so my logic is transparent to collections/streams, but I really need to make the comparison multiside, not one by one in the inside

Comment: @user1352530: your request makes no sense. collections and streams and all other related operations will call a comparator with exactly two elements and you have to implement that operation to conform. Point. And once you have such an operation, there are built-in operations for three or more elements, as shown. As [Magnamag has pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201448/multiobject-comparable-comparator-interface/29206764?noredirect=1#comment46615289_29201448), your request looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I asked if there is any similar standard mechanism in Java. Not XY. My doubt is whether there is an specification for multiside comparisons, and specially if it's used internally by collections and streams for max(), sorted() and other operations

Comment: @user1352530: You said, word by word **I really need to make the comparison multiside**, again you said **I really need** so you didn’t ask, “whether there is an specification for” or about something that is “internally by collections and streams” (what would be the point about something that is used internally). You have been told multiple times that there is no such thing and that you should tell what the *actual problem* is that you are trying to solve. The fact that you keep telling that you “really need” the thing that doesn’t exist is exactly what XY is about. Click on that link and read

Comment: Sorry I'm bad wording in english. I'm sorry

Comment: i express it bad, i'll accept this answer as the most complete and open a new one with a concrete exampel

Answer (score 1):

The problem with comparing multiple objects at once is what to return.
A Java comparator returns -1 if the first object is "smaller than the second one, 0 if they are equals and 1 if the first one is the "bigger" one.

If you compare more than two objects, an integer wouldn't suffice to describe the difference between said objects.

Comment: It does not _have_ to return -1 or 1; it has to return a negative or positive integer. Only 0 is a "hard" requirement.

Comment: Well, you could say if it's bigger, equal or smaller than ANY of the objects or customize the returned integer ponderate according to prevalence. The thing is I need to use information from the total of elements for more complex comparisons.

Comment: If you really need to make it as an implantation of the compare method, you could do a comparator that takes two objects of class Object, then cast o1 to your Class, cast o2 to a list of objects from that class and then compare o1 to each item of o2 (which is the list).
I would advice against this, that's the definition of ugly code.

Comment: As a last resort perhaps I'll do.. I want the interface to be fully understandable by collections and streams mechanisms

Comment: That is the problem of the current implementation of comparator. But I am looking for a superinterface, a non-related mechanism, I don't know, whatever it allows me to define a multiside comparing logic without having to recreate all the java interfaces for collections, queues, streams..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a normal `Comparable<T>` you can combine it any way you want. From being able to compare two things you can build anything (see different sorting algorithms, which usually only need a `<` implementation).

For example here's a naive one for "you could say if it's bigger, equal or smaller than ANY of the objects"

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T... toCompare) {
    if (toCompare.length < 2) throw Nothing to compare; // or return something
    T first = toCompare[0];
    int smallerCount;
    int equalCount;
    int biggerCount;
    for(int i = 1, n = toCompare.length; i < n; ++i) {
        int compare = first.compareTo(toCompare[i]);
        if(compare == 0) {
            equalCount++;
        } else if(compare < 0) {
            smallerCount++;
        } else {
            biggerCount++;
        }
    }
    return someCombinationOf(smallerCount, equalCount, biggerCount);
}
```

However I couldn't figure out a proper way of combining them, what about the sequence `(3, 5, 3, 1)` where `3` is smaller than `5`, equal to `3` and bigger than `1`, so all counts are `1`; here all your "it's bigger, equal or smaller than ANY" conditions are true at the same time, however you could return the counts as an object if it helps to defer the combination of counts to a later point in time.

Comment: The problem is it wouldn't take profit of the comparator standarness anymore (collections, streams) as it would be a custom comparator/comparable implementation

Comment: Khm, please... in your question you said "The signature would be `compare(T... toCompare)`". I saw you updated the question, this is really XY Problem :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for my wording. Of course I know I can implement whatever I want, but I am (mistakenly) trying to describe a mechanism approach that is standard, I mean that is used by java internals, so I don't have to extend collections, streams and anything. I just find surprising there is no preprovided mechanism for integrating collections ,streams, queues with a comparing interface that allows you compare n to n. What if I need to compare based on the average of the group? and so on

Comment: Hmm, that last part is interesting: "compare n to n. [...] compare based on the average?", in that case you'll need a simple `Comparator<Collection<T>>`: `compare(Collection<T> a, Collection<T> b) { return Integer.compare(calcAvg(a), calcAvg(b)); }`. You can even implement lexicographical sorting this way between `List<T>`s. You can use this `Comparator` with any collections API (Java, Guava, Apache, Streams, ...).

Comment: Sorry, today's not my day, I meant 1 to n. For instance, the max function returns the element so that element is the winner of a comparison mechanism, custom implemented, of it against ALL the others, not the winner of n battles 1 vs 1

Comment: So you have `x`, and `(a, b, c)` and you want `x <?> avgOrMax(a, b, c)`?

Comment: I have (Pineapple,Pizza,Yogurt), and max returns the item such that my custom 1 -> n comparison returns biggest quotient. This quotient  could be something like degreeOfYumie. So Pineapple is more yummie than Pizza+Yogurt, Pizza is equally yummie than Pineapple+yogurt, and Yogurt is equally yummie than Pizza+Pineapple. So the winner is Pineaple. If I did that unitary, all the ingredients would be equally yummie.